# Integral from MIT Integration Bee Qualifiers 2019

Tags: integration, limits, gaussian-integral

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^{2n}} dx$$

This question is the 12th question from the MIT Integration Bee Qualifiers 2019.
Can someone provide a full solution to this problem?

The answer is 2.

Comment: For $-1<x<1$ we have $x^{2n}\rightarrow 0$ and for $|x|>1$ we have $x^{2n}\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: This is a nice problem to figure out yourself. Try to study it step by step: What is the limit $L(x)$ of $-x^{2n}$ as $n\to\infty$ for different values of $x$? What is the exponential of this limit? Finally what is the integral of this? This, while not being a full proof, will tell you what you should expect the limit to be and give you an idea of what exactly you need to prove.

Comment: Will try, thanks for the tip

Comment: Recently it was published a book about the MIT integration bee, under the title " MIT Integration Bee, Solutions of Qualifying Tests from 2010 to 2023" You can simply find it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Remark.* Based on the comments to your question, I will mark a great part of my answer as a spoiler so you can figure it out yourself.

*Hint.* Use the Dominated Convergence Theorem by Lebesgue

*Full Solution.*

> Let $-1<x<1$. Then $$\lim_{n\to\infty} x^{2n}=0$$ so that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \exp(-x^{2n})=1.$$
>  Also, when $x<-1$ or $1<x$, $x^{2n}$ goes to $\infty$ so that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \exp(-x^{2n})=0.$$
> It follows that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \exp(-x^{2n})=\begin{cases}1,&-1<x<1\\0,&x<-1\text{ or }1<x\end{cases}.$$
> Since all the integrands are uniformly bounded by $$\begin{cases}1,&-1\le x\le 1\\\exp(-x^2), &x<-1\text{ or }1<x\end{cases},$$ which is even a Schwartz function, we have by Lebesgue that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^{2n}} \,\mathrm dx=\int_{-1}^11\,\mathrm dx=2.$$